# windows mobile wireless networks

Tags: windows-mobile

Hai i am new to windows mobile application i didn't know how to programatically list the number of wireless network(wifi) and their access point in my mobile can any one give a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the compact framework you can take a look at the [OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx). There is a free community edition as well as paid versions. 
More specifically look at the [OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation Namespace](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/)